# HTML5 Voice API - Resetting Result Array

Tags: javascript, html, voice-recognition

I'm using the HTML5 voice API for a project. I'm having trouble trying to set the result array: `event.results`.

I'm listening for '[A-H][0-9] "INTO" [A-H][0-9] "GO"'. When I hear "GO", I want to reset the events.result array. I have to listen for the same input again, but the first input cannot be removed from the event.results array.

I've tried:

```
event.results = [];
event.results.length = 0;
```

None of these work. I've also looked up the API and I can't find the solution to what I'm trying to do.

A similar example to what I want to do, would be if it was listening for any sequence of words. But when it heard the word "Cancel", it would forget everything it had just heard.

I hope this makes sense and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the results are held in a `SpeechRecognitionList`, but I couldn't find any api for manipulating the list itself.
What does work is stopping and restarting the recognition, but that's problematic if you're not using a https-site (on a plain http site the browser always asks for permission when restarting recognition).

Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>voice api test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>voice api test</h1>
    <main></main>
    <script>
    (function startRecognizing() {
        var main = document.querySelector('main');
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.addEventListener('result', function (event) {
            var lastResult = event.results[event.results.length - 1];
            if (lastResult[0].transcript.indexOf('cancel') > -1) {
                recognition.stop();
                while (main.children.length) main.removeChild(main.children[0]);
                startRecognizing();
            } else {
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lastResult[0].transcript));
                main.appendChild(p);
            }
        });
        recognition.start();
    }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, stopping and restarting isn't any use as it's not a HTTPS site. I considered this, but it's not really plausible to have the user click "Allow" all the time. But thanks for your post :)